# Devise's edit user page doesn't want to save a text area I've added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

As the title says, I've added a text area to devise's edit page, but whenever I click Update, it doesn't update it, it just stays blank all the time.

Here's my edit view:

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :current_goals %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :current_goals, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <br />
      <em><%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum</em>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %></p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

**application_controller**:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:other_attributes, :current_goals) }
end
```

However, if I don't define a method called `current_goals` in my **user.rb**, rails will give me an error, undefined method current_goals.

**user.rb**

```
def current_goals
end
```

How do I make it save the information I give it?

Comment: have you added `current_goals` attribute to your table ?

Comment: Yes, I have.

Here is the code from my DB:
    add_column :users, :current_goals, :text

Comment: override the devise `registration_controller` strong parameters.

Comment: You shouldn't have to create a method if you added a field with a migration. Are you sure you ran it/restarted the rails server?

Comment: Yes, I'm totally sure. 

Here it is

class AddFieldsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :username, :string
    add_column :users, :current_goals, :text
    add_column :users, :achieved_goals, :text
  end
end

Then I ran rake db:migrate. I've restarted the server several times already.

Comment: @Emu Okay, but what would I have to write in the new controller?

Sorry, I'm still new to Rails.

Comment: @SvetoslavTodorov, Check this: http://jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html

Comment: @Emu That didn't fix the problem. I get another error now. Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session' You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

I checked out the guide, but it doesn't really say anything related, only about resources.